# Unique Rank for each Student based on Marks and Time | Mysql | RDBMS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rdbms

I am trying to create an online test application using PHP & Mysql. My mysql table `students` will have the following structure :

```
 | id | username | marks | time | rank |
```

I want to affect an unique rank to each student based on their marks and time, higher mark and lower time giving higher rank.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you really just want `order by marks DESC, time ASC`? Also in what order should it count. Someone who finished within a minute should rank high or low when their mark is only 10% or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you shouldn't store the rank into the table, as it is a computed value that will likely change each time you add a new row. Then, if you want to get the ranking of each student, you can do something like that :

```
select 
  students.*, 
  (@rank := @rank+1) AS rank 
from students 
inner join (select @rank := 0) as a 
order by mark desc, time asc;
```

Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b4b8/6).

Comment: What if i want to display the rank of a particular student ?

Comment: You could store the result into a table then select from it, or count the number of student having a higher rank. For more recurring usage, I would advise a `ranks` table kept up-to-date using triggers when doing something on the `students` table.

Comment: what if all the criteria matches, the student has to be given equal rank but it does not give